# Enable absolute ordering in spring using java based configuration instead of xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8

I want to add/enable the `absolute-ordering` using java code configuration. Below is the xml  based configuration we do in `web.xml`

```
<absolute-ordering/>
```

I am having a class that is configured using @Congiguration and @EnableWebMvc and another class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` interface.

Comment: You cannot. You can only enable that through a `web-fragment.xml` or `web.xml`.

Comment: In that case, does java base configuration and web.xml can go hand in hand?

Comment: Yes as it has always been.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

Apparently you have multiple `spring-web` or `spring-webmvc` jars on your class path.
Or another dependencies that contributes that file as well.
**Remove** the source jars from your classpath.
Name of the file are
`spring-web-5.3.0-sources.jar` and
`spring-webmvc-5.3.0-sources.jar`

I found the solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296368/absolute-ordering-not-working-more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring-web)

For xml base configuration make use of:
add `<absolute-ordering />` tag to your web.xml just under the  tag. should work fine.